# Converting a set of SVGs to a OTF font in JS

Tags: javascript, fonts, converters

As the title already describes, I'm looking to convert a set of SVGs (stored as text inside of an object/array, depending on the needs) into an OTF font inside the users browser.

I didn't find any help online, so can anyone else change that?

Comment: You might check [opentype.js]:(https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js#user-content-writing-a-font). I guess you will have to convert betwween svg commands and post script syntax. So it's most certrainly not super convenient

Comment: starting with opentype.js makes sense, "converting to post script syntax" does not. OpenType fonts don't use postscript (they use TTf, which is nothing like postscript, or CFF/CFF2, which use an instruction set similar to but also very different from postcript. Or: SVG, which is a 100% valid OpenType table format and has been for years now)

Comment: Also, note that there are quite a few libraries that can be easily googled for, so if you want proper help, talk about all the various things you already found, tried, and how those didn't work. In absence of that, you're still on the hook for first [searching and researching](/help/how-to-ask) yourself.

Comment: I did check opentype.js already and didn't find any way to throw an entire SVG (as a string) at it and have it give me back an OTF at some point.